# Format numpy array of timestamps into a concatenated string

Tags: python, pandas, string, numpy

I have an array of unix timestamps:

```
d = {'timestamp': [1551675611, 1551676489, 1551676511, 1551676533, 1551676554]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
timestamps = df[['timestamp']].values
```

That I would like to format into a concatenated string, like so:

```
'1551675611;1551676489;1551676511;1551676533;1551676554'
```

So far I have prepared this:

```
def format_timestamps(timestamps: np.array) -> str:
    timestamps = ";".join([f"{timestamp:f}" for timestamp in timestamps])
    return timestamps
```

Running:

```
format_timestamps(timestamps)
```

Gives the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.__format__
```

Since I'm new to python I'm having trouble understanding how I can fix the error

Comment: replace "{timestamp:f}" with "{timestamp[0]}", does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why the error?

You're getting this error because of how you extract the `'timestamp'` column values with the following line:

```py
timestamps = df[['timestamp']].values
```

Accessing DataFrame column values passing a `list` of column names as here will return a multi-dimensional ndarray with the top-level containing ndarray objects containing values for each column name listed for each row in the DataFrame. This approach is generally only useful when selecting multiple columns by name.

The error is being thrown by your function because each`timestamp` here:

```py
";".join([f"{timestamp:f}" for timestamp in timestamps])
```

Is an ndarray containing a single value when `timestamps` is defined as in your original post - where a `str` value would be desirable/expected.

### Accounting for the error

To remedy this error in your code, simply replace:

```py
timestamps = df[['timestamp']].values
```

With:

```py
timestamps = df['timestamp'].values
```

By passing a single `str` to extract a single column from your DataFrame, `timestamps` will here be defined as a one-dimensional ndarray with `'timestamp'` column values for each row stored within - which will pass through your original `format_timestamps` without error.

### `format_timestamps`

Running `format_timestamps(timestamps)` using the above approach and your original implementation of `format_timestamps` will return:

```
'1551675611.000000;1551676489.000000;1551676511.000000;1551676533.000000;1551676554.000000'
```

This is better (no errors at least) but still not quite what you want. This root of this issue is that you are passing `f` as a format specifier when joining `timestamp` values, this will format each value as a `float` when in actuality you want to format each value as an `int` (format specifier `d`).

You can either, change your format specifier from `f` to `d` in your function definition.

```py
def format_timestamps(timestamps: np.array) -> str:
    timestamps = ";".join([f"{timestamp:d}" for timestamp in timestamps])
    return timestamps
```

Or simply not pass a format specifier - as `timestamps` values are already `numpy.int64` type.

```py
def format_timestamps(timestamps: np.array) -> str:
    timestamps = ";".join([f"{timestamp}" for timestamp in timestamps])
    return timestamps
```

Running `format_timestamps(timestamps)` using either definition above will return what you're after:

```
'1551675611;1551676489;1551676511;1551676533;1551676554'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because in your list comprehension, `timestamp` is a `numpy.ndarray` object. Just flatten first and convert to string:

```
>>> ";".join(timestamps.flatten().astype(str))
'1551675611;1551676489;1551676511;1551676533;1551676554'
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have pandas, why not consider a pandaic solution with `str.cat`:

```
df['timestamp'].astype(str).str.cat(sep=';')
# '1551675611;1551676489;1551676511;1551676533;1551676554'
```

If NaNs or invalid data are a possibility, you can handle them with `pd.to_numeric`:

```
(pd.to_numeric(df['timestamp'], errors='coerce')
   .dropna()
   .astype(int)
   .astype(str)
   .str.cat(sep=';'))
# '1551675611;1551676489;1551676511;1551676533;1551676554'
```

---

Another idea is to iterate over the list of timestamps and join:

```
';'.join([f'{t}' for t in  df['timestamp'].tolist()])
# '1551675611;1551676489;1551676511;1551676533;1551676554'
```

Comment: `.str.cat` ah, always forget about that guy.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix to your code would be:

```
def format_timestamps(timestamps: np.array) -> str:
    timestamps = ";".join([f"{timestamp[0]}" for timestamp in timestamps])
    return timestamps
```

Here I only replaced `timestamp:f` with `timestamp[0]`, so you get each timestamp as a scalar instead of an array